# XLST Run For-Each to check node value and update variable

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to run the equivalent of an overall pass/fail.

I want it to check node-x, test if node-x is > or < 2.5, and update a variable based on the results. I want it to run through the whole set to see if any fail...

```
<xsl:variable name="overallPassFail" select="'true'" />
    <xsl:for-each select="MsmtValueNode">
        <xsl:variable name="EachValue" select="MsmtValueNode" />
            <xsl:if test="$EachValue &gt; 2.5">
                <xsl:variable name="overallPassFail" select="'false'" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$EachValue &lt; 2.5">
                <xsl:variable name="overallPassFail" select="'true'" />
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($overallPassFail = 'true')">
        <div class="status_label_overview status_label_passed_overview">
              Passed
        </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="status_label_overview status_label_failed_overview">
              Failed
        </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

It isn't updating the variable "overallPassFail" as I think it would, so looking for some help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: How does your XML sample data look? Does it have elements named `MsmtValueNode` with numeric values? Are they also nested (otherwise using `<xsl:variable name="EachValue" select="MsmtValueNode" />` inside of a an `<xsl:for-each select="MsmtValueNode">` doesn't make sense)? It is not clear to me whether you want a true if there is (at least one) `MsmtValueNode` smaller than 2.5 or whether you are looking for false if there is at least one greater than 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.

Yes, the MsmtValueNode has a numeric value, they are nested - an in the exact code I use the explicit path /path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/MsmtValueNode

Maybe I'm not understanding something - why not start with true, so any value greater than 2.5 sets it to false - I tried doing it in the other order but the $overall variable doesn't seem to be updating...

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example  input and the expected output. In general, there is no need to "update a variable" - and variables in XSLT cannot be modified. OTOH it is very easy to test if any one (or all) nodes in a set satisfy a condition, using a single test expression.

Comment: P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update with the min reprex shortly - first time diving in here. XLST v2.0 (which I'll also add to the min reprex

Comment: Not the main issue here, but do note that your tests do not cover the eventuality of `$EachValue = 2.5`. As a rule, when you deal with mutually exclusive options, `xsl:choose` is preferable to multiple `xsl:if`s.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k - your answer and sample helped simplify and resolve this for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following **minimal** example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <MsmtValueNode>2.5</MsmtValueNode>
    <MsmtValueNode>2.4</MsmtValueNode>
    <MsmtValueNode>2.6</MsmtValueNode>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <div>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="MsmtValueNode &lt; 2.5">Failed</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Passed</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>Failed</div>
```

**Explanation**

A comparison of a sequence to a single value is true when there is at least one value in the sequence that has the required magnitude relationship to the single value - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-general-comparisons.