# XSLT XML to CSV looping through tags and set a variable to true of a condition is met

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am looking to write a xslt where it ierates through dates and sets ispast to true in csv if any one value is true

xmls looks like below

```xml
<inst >
    <mast id=1>
        <dates>
            <date>
                <filedate>2022</filedate>
                <ispast>false</filedate>
            </date>
            <date>
                <filedate>2023</filedate>
                <ispast>false</filedate>
            </date>
            <date>
                <filedate>2020</filedate>
                <ispast>true</filedate>
            </date>
        </dates>
    </mast>
    <mast id=2>
        <dates>
            <date>
                <filedate>2022</filedate>
                <ispast>false</filedate>
            </date>
            <date>
                <filedate>2023</filedate>
                <ispast>false</filedate>
            </date>
            <date>
                <filedate>2025</filedate>
                <ispast>false</filedate>
            </date>
        </dates>
    </mast>
</inst>
```

Output CSV

```
id,ispast
1,true
2,false
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74120718/3016153

Comment: Please at least post a valid XML input. Your root element is not closed and the <ispast> elements are closed with </filedate>...

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in terms of a low-level procedural approach to this problem. With XSLT you need to think more declaratively. With a `dates` element as context node, you can test whether at least one date has `ispast="true"` with the expression

```
<xsl:variable name="ispast" select="exists(date[ispast='true'])"/>
```