# How to iterate through object collection in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am working on a system where the users, amongst other things, help their customers invest in specific funds. Upon confirmation of engagement, a series of documents are created, for which we use XSLT templates. In one of these templates I am trying to iterate through a collection of selected funds and their properties.

Since our code contains customer sensitive informations, I have anonymized object names in the example code.

On case creation I have an object containing a `List<SelectedFund>`. `SelectedFund` has a property `FundNo` (string). If this property in one (or more) of the list items has a specific value ('1', '75', '76' etc.), a specific text section should be added to the document. My current solution is to add a variable in the XSLT template, which is set to `true` or `false` based on the `FundNo` values. Then later on I'm doing a `<xsl:if>` on that variable to see if the section should be added. However this doesn't work for me.

```
<xsl:variable name="ShowInformationSection">
  <xsl:for-each select="Case/Investment/SelectedFunds">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="
            (Case/BrokerCompany/NickName = 'Investment broker') and
            (SelectedFund/FundNo = '1' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '75' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '76' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '82')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

I suspect that while the collection is iterated, the variable value is set on every iteration based on the current item. So the actual variable value comes down to the `FundNo` value on the last item iterated. Obviously this doesn't work.

I was hoping that XSLT had a `contains()` function or similar. And it does, but this function only works on strings and not object collections. Are there any other way of checking (in XSLT) if a collection contains specific property values. My last option is to handle this in the business logic, which I am trying to avoid for now.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74120718/3016153.

Comment: I agree with Michael the question is a bit unclear. Can you please show some example source XML and a sample output? It sounds like you want to insert some boilerplate text only in the case that the set of values of a certain set of elements have an intersection with another set of string values, and you're looking for a way to express that test condition. Is that right? Because if so the question's title isn't particularly accurate. Please tag your question to show what version of XSLT you are running, because in XSLT 2 or later this has a simpler solution than in XSLT 1

Comment: When people don't show the XML, it usually means that they haven't understood how sensitive XPath is to context, which in turn tends to mean that the context for the expression is wrong: usually either the namespace context, or the current node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="ShowInformationSection" select="boolean(Case/Investment/SelectedFunds[
            (Case/BrokerCompany/NickName = 'Investment broker') and
            (SelectedFund/FundNo = '1' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '75' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '76' or 
            SelectedFund/FundNo = '82')])"/>
```

to get the variable `ShowInformationSection` as true if there is a `Case/Investment/SelectedFunds` element for which the predicate `(Case/BrokerCompany/NickName = 'Investment broker') and (SelectedFund/FundNo = '1' or  SelectedFund/FundNo = '75' or  SelectedFund/FundNo = '76' or  SelectedFund/FundNo = '82')` holds and have it being false otherwise.